# compiling assembly with Visual C++ Express 2010 64 Bit

Tags: visual-c++, assembly

How do I compile assembly code in a separate file?

If my function is of the type "void __fastcall foo(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long&, unsigned long long&)", how do I implement this in my .asm file?

Comment: Where is the emphasis? On "How do I compile assembly" or "how do I implement this"? I have a Hello World example, which compiles fine in a separate file, but that is not a function implementation. I use FASM, integrated with VC++ Express.

Answer (score 0):

```
.code

foo PROC
            ; do stuff here
foo ENDP

end
```